# Rename field values in list that occur twice

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how I can rename values using python if they occur twice in a list, here `job['audio']`.

Following example given:

```
job['audio'] = list(map(lambda x: build_audio(x), fileInfo['stream']['audio']))
```

Where `job['audio']` contains the following:

```
[
{'index': 1, 'type': 'audio', 'codec': 'aac', 'channels': 2, 'bitrate': 196622, 'hls': {'codec': 'mp4a.40.2', 'codec_name': 'aac', 'name': 'English', 'language': 'en', 'group_id': [], 'auto_select': True, 'default': False}, 'options': {'mode': 0}}, 
{'index': 2, 'type': 'audio', 'codec': 'aac', 'channels': 2, 'bitrate': 196976, 'hls': {'codec': 'mp4a.40.2', 'codec_name': 'aac', 'name': 'Deutsch', 'language': 'de', 'group_id': [], 'auto_select': True, 'default': False}, 'options': {'mode': 0}}, 
{'index': 3, 'type': 'audio', 'codec': 'aac', 'channels': 2, 'bitrate': 197534, 'hls': {'codec': 'mp4a.40.2', 'codec_name': 'aac', 'name': 'English', 'language': 'en', 'group_id': [], 'auto_select': True, 'default': False}, 'options': {'mode': 0}}
]
```

How can I rename `'name'` and `'language'` if they occur twice. I guess that I have to use set and `for i, audio in enumerate(job['audio']):` but I'm not sure how to access the fields within my list.

The result I want to have for index 3 should be `'name': 'English2'` and `'language': 'en2'`

Comment: For each attribute you want to update, iterate over all items, tracking which values for that attribute you've seen and how many times, update each according to that tracking.

Comment: Well I already saw some example onto that, but they all don't show how to go for dictionary with mixed keys and in general they also don't show how I can possibly access only these two fields (name, language). I mean none of the 3 lines shown are really equal, they all have a different bitrate for example. So a comparison of the whole line won't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sets to hold the names and languages that have already been seen. If you encounter a duplicate, update it.

```
nameset = set()
langset = set()

for row in job['audio']:
    if row['hls']['name'] in nameset:
        row['hls']['name'] += '2'
    else:
        nameset.add(row['hls']['name'])
    if row['hls']['language'] in langset:
        row['hls']['language'] += '2'
    else:
        langset.add(row['hls']['language'])
```

Note that this only works if there's just one duplicate. If you need to handle more duplicates, and have them increment to `en3`, `en4`, etc. you can use a dictionary instead of a set. The dictionary would contain the current counter for that name, which you increment after each repetition.